# How to backtrace a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large and complicated system consisting of `php` and `javascript` code, which make many `mysql` queries. Is there a way to 'backtrace' each `mysql` query to the exact line of code, which makes the query?

In `mysql` it is possible to trace all queries (adding a `log` statement to the `mysql` config), but it does not show which `php` or `javascript` code/module/line did the query. Is it possible to find the offending lines for each `mysql` query?

Comment: I'd suppose you would need to to fwrite a txt file after each successful query, i.e. create your own log file. It's not that difficult.

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding something, if you have a good text editor, you could just do a search on `mysql`... you should find all the queries...

Comment: ...and by the way, what do you mean by "offending lines"? are you getting errors or do you just want to get rid of mysql (which you should, by the way)?

Comment: But I wonder if there is a more convenient way, as there are about 100 queries in the code...

Comment: Not really. Mysql simply doesn't know where calls are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way of MySQL knowing what line of code, class, function or file you're making a call from. It just receives a socket connection from the application running the code, and accepts input, processes it and returns a result.

All it knows about is the data it receives, and who is sending it.

You can view active connections and a brief description of what they're doing using

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

You'll get output similar to this:

```
Id  User    Host        db  Command Time    State   Info
48  test    10.0.2.2:65109  test    Sleep   4621        
51  test    10.0.2.2:49717  test    Sleep   5       
52  test    10.0.2.2:49718  test    Query   0       SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Generally when people want to log queries it happens somewhat similar to this

1. Before the query is run, log the query and any parameters
2. Run the query
3. Log the success/failure of the query, and any errors

To execute this process for systems with hundreds or thousands of queries, you'll generally find a wrapper function/class is created which accepts the appropriate parameters, processes the query as listed above, and returns the result. You could pass your wrapper method the [PHP Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` when you call it, to then log where the database call is being initiated from.

**pseudo code only**

```
// Wrapper method
function query_wrapper($stm, $file, $line)
{
  log_prequery($stm, $file, $line); // Log the query, file and line
  $result = $stm->execute(); // Execute the query
  log_postquery($result); // Log the result (and any errors)
  return $result; // Return the result
}

// In your code where you're making a database query
$db = new Database();
$stm = $db->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar");
query_wrapper($stm, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: `debug_backtrace` would enable you to see what file/line was called in PHP. You don't need `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. It still requires a wrapper function to be used though.

Comment: Be extremely careful if you do use `debug_backtrace`, it can be a very expensive function and can slow down your scripts/applications considerably.

Comment: This is very true, and I'd assume that he'd *only* use it when he needs debugging (and not all the time).

Comment: The wrapper method has worked for me. Even with `debug_backtrace`. Thanks.